# Gateway GT5228 Problems after installation

Tags: 14.10

I've tried Ubuntu, Xubuntu, & Lubuntu. The latter two did not even make it to the install screen, however the former managed to install without a hitch. All were the latest versions. As stated in the title, I have a Gateway GT5228 with all the stock hardware, except for an extra hdd & disc drive. That's a dual core AMD Athlon X2 4200+ & a Nvidia GeForce 6100. Ubuntu makes it to the desktop and then freezes. I can't bring up the command window or anything, all I can do at that point is hold down the power button and try something else.

I'm curious if this is a common problem or if it's something with my computer. I can run windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit just fine & Win 8 & Win xp. Any info would be appreciated, I haven't found much on my specific model having problems with Ubuntu.

thanks!

Comment: can you log in using TTY1?  (if you don't know what that is, drop me a note @Fabby)

Comment: I have no clue what that is honestly. & I don't know how to "drop a note" either lol.

Comment: It seems you have a [well-known problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)  (and the comment you just made was "dropping me a note" as well!)  ;-)

Comment: I've gotten it all straightened out using that method plus a few tweaks, thanks !